# npm install zmq giving error as node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, zeromq

i am really stuck with this problem and my dev haults, did lot of google search but confused what is the solution, i am sure any i will get help in this forum.

i am on ubuntu 13.04
node - 0.11.10-pre
zmq already installed through standard process below:
http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software 
python - 2.7

```
zishan@news01:~$ sudo npm install zmq
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zmq
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zmq
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/set-immediate
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/set-immediate

zmq@2.5.1 install /home/zishan/node_modules/zmq
node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:65:16)
gyp ERR! stack at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) as install
gyp ERR! stack at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:150:20)
gyp ERR! stack at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:93:9
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:694:7)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:104:17)
gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (child_process.js:808:16)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (childprocess.js:875:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/zishan/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! zmq@2.5.1 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.5.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! cwd /home/zishan
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/zishan/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947145/error-pre-versions-of-node-cannot-be-installed-use-the-nodedir-flag-instea)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i figured it out using below links

First i removed nodejs completely using below.
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

then, i installed the Node version manager to install node 0.10 (which is stable version)
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

All is working like a charm and zmq installed with no issues.

I think earlier i was using node 0.11.xx-pre version which is in beta and have issues with node-gyp, node 0.10 is working without issues.

hope this will help someone else as it took me long time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Node version is too high and therefore not compatible. Read:

`...
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
...`

If you downgrade Node and retry you should be good to go. Note that that it is quite important to have your Xcode path at the correct place. Use `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`

Also use `brew --config` to make sure other things are in order.