# Path to Node.js Installation in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu (linux).

I installed node.js for a project.

Recently I am getting this error on `npm install`.

> Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead

I found a stack link below as

[Node pre error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947145/error-pre-versions-of-node-cannot-be-installed-use-the-nodedir-flag-instea)

Under the solution it asks for the directory where node.js is installed and currently i am clueless where the nodejs is installed.

Please help me on how can I locate the directory where node.js is installed.

Comment: Which way did you used to install node.js ? Compile it from source or per package manager ? You can find the path of node with the terminal command locate, but it should be under /usr/bin/nodejs i think

Comment: What does `which nodejs` or `which node` output? It seems like you installed node manually instead of using `apt-get`.

Comment: I installed from here http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs

Comment: I installed it by cloning git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Quick explanation**

You have a version with `-pre`. Get rid of it and put the latest **stable** version from nodejs.org.

You can use `which` to locate a command. For your case, type `which nodejs`.

EDIT: The answer from your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947145/error-pre-versions-of-node-cannot-be-installed-use-the-nodedir-flag-instea) is referring to the path of node source code, not the nodejs binary.

Comment: /usr/bin/nodejs
This is being printed on typing which nodejs

Comment: can you tell me what version of node you installed? Probably you end up using a version with -pre behind. If you have the source from where you installed nodejs go and `sudo make uninstall`. Download the stable version from nodejs.org and install it.

Comment: v0.11.14-pre, so I need to uninstall this and install a stable build?

Comment: Yup. I think is easier this way :) and should work with the stable version

Comment: `which` is specific to Linux only?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, most software can be installed from the built-in repositories. This updates it for you (even if it's sometimes a bit outdated).

To install the stable version the Ubuntu way, install the `nodejs-legacy` package (after uninstalling your version):

```
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
```

To use the latest, refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/663052/438156 (my answer), or https://askubuntu.com/a/711976/438156 (bit more involved, more the Ubuntu way).